# Timing out tests with Green unit test runner

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-green

I have the following setup I use to run my tests with py.test using timeout plugin:

```
 venv/bin/py.test-3.4 --timeout=200 --durations=10 cryptoassets
```

(From https://bitbucket.org/miohtama/cryptoassets/src/bf2c3affa5528c6e96bfcc96b0caf4b0c9a9ec27/cryptoassets/core/tests/droneio-run-tests.sh?at=master )

I am using an external CI service. They have 15 minute limit on the tests run. As my tests depend on third party API services, randomly tests may hang. Thus, I use py.test timeout plugin to weed out these test cases and make sure the tests run somewhat normally.

Does *green* provide any similar mechanism to make sure that the one test doesn't keep blocking others forever?

Answer (score 1):

No, currently green does not include any timeout functionality.

[I created an enhancement issue](https://github.com/CleanCut/green/issues/45) to track the feature request.  Would you mind answering the question I posed there?